# How should I loop through all mentioned users | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**My Question**

I want to make a discord bot that loops through all mentioned users and gets their ID, and roles. How would I do that?

**My Code**

```
client.on('message', message => {
  for(var i = 0, l = message.mentions.users.size; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(message.mentions.users.values())
  };
})
```

**What it returns**

```
[Map Iterator] {
  User {
    id: '809566556836200459',
    system: null,
    locale: null,
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 64 },
    username: 'Chusk',
    bot: false,
    discriminator: '1927',
    avatar: '85d4d86d80915fdf44626d28596b8bba',
    lastMessageID: '875131427199533076',
    lastMessageChannelID: '736626786947039242'
  }
}
```

I want it to loop through all mentioned users and sees if they have a certain role, then execute a function if they do.

Comment: I wonder if you should be accessing the `users.length` property. Also inside the loop, maybe something like `console.log(message.mentions.users[i])` might give you a better idea which properties are available for the user (perhap role is in here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both, [`MessageMentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) and [`MessageMentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members), return a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), you can map it by ID.

---

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    const users = message.mentions.users.map((user) => user.id);
    console.log(users);
});
```